# Sass combine class and element selector

Tags: css, sass

Seems to me I should be able to combine the following code with `&`:

```
.nav-link {
  cursor: pointer;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

But for the likes of me, this fails. Suggestions?

Comment: Maybe over think it is just be seperated with a ",".

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for something like this:

```
.nav-link,
button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```